# Why do you see future Trinity in Architect's scene

Tags: the-matrix

In the Architect scene, on the monitors, when The Architect mentions that Neo loves Trinity and the screens starts showing her, you can see scenes that will be shown within next 2 min - Trinity is fighting Agent.

This can't be previous versions of the Matrix as the previous ones didn't have Trinity (I think?). Hmmm, now that I think about it, Trinity could have been in previous versions and everything could have played out same way on all versions of the matrix. Just in previous ones Neo didn't love Trinity... But then many things would have played out differently in original Matrix movie, and only Neo was engineered... Any thoughts?

Comment: Duplicate of [How did the Architect know Trinity would die?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208606/how-did-the-architect-know-trinity-would-die).

Comment: I've voted to close. The duplicate indicates that (in-universe) he confidently predicted that Trinity would fight the agents, something she herself imagined in an earlier scene. Out-of-universe, they lazily recycled some footage instead of filming an entirely new sceen

Comment: That's not an answer, but rather a shot at speculation. Was hoping this was explained by Wachowskis.

Comment: They explained almost *nothing* about the plot. They did the bare minimum of interviews required by the studio and talked almost exclusively about philosophy and cinematography.

Comment: Huh, interesting why would they do that. Is it their standard behavior? Or just only for the Matrix movies?

Comment: It's been their 'thing' all along. They didn't even do a director's audio commentary for the Matrix and the sequels, they just hired a bunch of philosophers and film critics to do it. Pointless to listen to, zero insight

Comment: Since the other Neos on the screens were [almost certainly predictions rather than recordings of previous cycles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76959/22250), it seems natural the Architect could also predict Trinity's situation in the very near future.